# Angular Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls)

Tags: json, angular

Angular Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls)

part of my angular.json :

```
        "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "preserveSymlinks": true,
        **"rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls": true,**
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
```

In the line "rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls": true, i got that problem : Property rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls is not allowed.

Please if anyone has an answer tell me and thank you !

Comment: I think this is clear. You just can not use the property: `rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls` there.
What are you trying to reach at the end? Could you tell us what's your target?

Comment: I downloaded a template from internet, I used to work with, but this time when I runed it first time without doing any changes I got that error, when i delete the line ( "rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls": true, ) and run it again I got that error : An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed.
See "C:\Users\steph\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-MF18pK\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Comment: Do you have the `ngcc` in your `package.json`? It stand for angular compatibility compiler. And also would be helpful if you post your angular version please. Just run `ng --version` in app root.

Comment: Are you using relative paths to `.scss` and/or to `.css` in `angular.json` file?

Comment: In my package.json I have :   "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 es5 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points --tsconfig \"./src/tsconfig.app.json\""                 and my angular version is : 11.0.5

Comment: yes I have both .css and .scss in my angular.json

Comment: But my question is if you are using a relative path for that. If yes, try to use the absolute path. Example: `"styles": [ "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                            "./node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css",
                            "src/assets/css/styles.css" ]`. Would be much helpful, if you add a stackblitz demo. Otherwise it's not easy to see what your code looks like.